# Call WebApi controller from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, controller, asp.net-web-api2

So I have two projects in my solution. Both are WebApi. I have controllers in both and I can call them from the client side - javascript. 
The problem is that I need to call a method in the controller of the second project from method in the controller of the first project. I also think I should state that the method I need to call is Post so I need to send it parameters as well.
Is this possible at all? I heard about "RedirectToAction" method but I think this won't work in webapi.

Comment: Every thing is the project is a class. So you can call it using instantiating and calling the method. You need to Desalinize the response which you get from the other project. You can go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741052/how-can-i-call-a-webapi-method-from-mvc-controller-action-method)

Answer (score 6):

You should not need to POST to the second controller.

Create some shared code in your project and have both controllers use this. If you have the variables needed for a POST in the first controller, you can simply pass these to the shared method.

Comment: interesting, I will try it. 
Is there a way to achieve that by making HTTP call from the first controller to the second one?

Comment: In theory, you could, but I honestly see little point. You will have all of the context available in the call to the first controller to call the shared method. All you are doing by creating a POST is adding overhead and complication.